# Algorithm of java replaceall method?

Tags: java, string, replace

I need algorithm of java replaceall method and ı want write this method only use charAt and length methods.I try but ı didnt do it please help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: java or javascript?

Comment: `I want write this method only use charAt and length methods.` ... Java's `String.replaceAll` also supports regex pattern matching, so throw a regex engine into your bag of needed tricks.

Comment: I voted to close this question because is off topic, this question don´t show effort...

Comment: Java is open-source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.replaceAll%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29

Comment: pshemo thanks to you. ım new at programming thanks for your helps

Comment: You are welcome. Also you can also find source code of classes in your JDK directory in `src.zip` archive. Many IDEs allows you to use this archive to easily preview this code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> **Your question isn't clear**.

I don't know what you want. Do you want the code replace *string* or *character* from other String? This is simple example for u.

```
public static String replace(String source,char oldChar,char newChar){
    char[] temp = source.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : temp) {
        if(c == oldChar){
            result.append(newChar);
        }else result.append(c);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Maybe it's solution you need, but I do not understand your question :/

```
public static String replaceStr(String source, String oldSR, String newSR) {
    List<Integer> positions = findPosition(source, oldSR);
    int lengthOldSr = oldSR.length();
    for (Integer position : positions) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
        int lengthSource = source.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthSource; i++) {
            if (position == i) {
                result.append(newSR);
                i += lengthOldSr - 1;
            } else {
                result.append(source.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        source = result.toString();
    }
    return source;
}

public static List<Integer> findPosition(String source, String oldSR) {
    int lengthOld = oldSR.length();
    int lengthSource = source.length();
    List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthSource; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < lengthOld; j++) {
            if ((j + i < lengthSource) && source.charAt(j + i) == oldSR.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == lengthOld) {
            positions.add(i);
        }
    }
    positions.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    return positions;
}
```

> INPUT : *source* **TUYENDEV 123 TUYENDEV 123 STACKOVER** , *old* **123** , *new* **456**
>
> OUTPUT : TUYENDEV 456 TUYENDEV 456 STACKOVER

Comment: //Thanks for your help. My method works as follow, and ı can use only charAt and length.//
1)Enter first string: do while if do if
2)Enter second string: do
3)Enter third string: for
output: for while if for if.

Comment: I have updated my answer.I hope this answer is helpful for you.